# Does a linear differential equation of a matrix variable have a closed form solution?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $X(t), A, B, C$ be matrices and $A, B, C$ are constant matrices. Does the following linear differential equation have a closed form solution?
$$
\frac{d X(t)}{dt} = A + BXC.
$$
Thank you!

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ are invertible, then it looks like $X(t)=-B^{-1}AC^{-1}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}B^kX(0)C^k$ works; if we put $L(X)=BXC$, then the series is just $\exp(tL)X(0)$.  I don't know about the non-invertible case.

Answer (score 0):

This expands user254433's answer. First, note that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left[\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}B^{k}MC^{k}\right]=B\left(\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{t^{k-1}}{\left(k-1\right)!}B^{k-1}MC^{k-1}\right)C=B\left(\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}B^{k}MC^{k}\right)C.
$$
Now, suppose $B$ and $C$ are nonsingular. Motivated by the above,
take
$$
X(t)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}B^{k}\left(X(0)+B^{-1}AC^{-1}\right)C^{k}-B^{-1}AC^{-1}
$$
as a solution. You can verify that the above is a solution directly:
$$
X^{\prime}(t)=B\left[\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}B^{k}\left(X(0)+B^{-1}AC^{-1}\right)C^{k}\right]C=A+BX(t)C.
$$